# Arguments as JSON kind of in sendTransactionProposal(req ChaincodeInvokeRequest) in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: json, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, shim, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

In regard to calling a chaincode(go lang) through fabric nodejs API, The Request Object for the method sendTransactionProposal(req ChaincodeInvokeRequest) the ChaincodeInvokeRequest accepts only Array. as arguments for the invoke method to be called, IS there any other way/mechanism to pass arguments say..JSON, name/values.. .. present ordered way of arguments looks very odd.I am referring to Fabric V1.2 https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/global.html#ChaincodeInvokeRequest.

Answer (score 0):

We can send only string arguments to the chaincode invoke request, still you can stringify the JSON and send it as an argument then you can parse it if you want in the chaincode.